# Show that a set of vectors is a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Q: show for any $\theta$ in $R$, set $S_{\theta} = {(cos\theta,sin\theta,0),(-sin\theta,cos\theta,0),(0,0,1)}$ is a basis for $R^3$

and here is what i have done so far,

a set of vectors is linearly independent if and only if we have $a_1v_1+a_2v_2...+a_nv_n = 0$

so $a_1(cos\theta,sin\theta,0)+a_2(-sin\theta,cos\theta,0)+a_3(0,0,1)$

and i get $a_3=0, a_1cos\theta=a_2sin\theta, -a_1sin\theta=a_2cos\theta$

i have to somehow show that $a_1,a_2=0$ but i can't figure it out from that equivalence..

+also, in order to prove that a set of vectors is a basis, i know i have to prove that not only its linearly independent, but also spans. But is it safe to say if its linearly independent then it must span?? hence, it is a basis??

Comment: Your definition of linearly independent isn't right. However, you're correct in saying that every collection of $n$-many linearly independent elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ must necessarily span $\mathbb{R}^n.$ This is because $\mathbb{R}$ is a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: which part is not right? @goblin

Comment: The correct definition is: an $n$-long sequence of vectors $v$ is linearly independent iff for each $n$-long sequence of scalars $a$, we have $$\sum_{i<n}a_i v_i = 0 \rightarrow \mathop{\forall}_{i<n} a_i = 0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta & 0 \\
-\sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then
$$
\det A=\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1\neq0
$$
so $A$ is invertible. But $A$ is invertible if and only if the rows of $A$ are linearly independent. Hence your vectors are a basis for $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Every orthogonal set of non-zero vectors is linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

To continue your attempt. $\frac{a_1}{a_2}=\frac{\sin(\theta}{\cos(\theta)}$ and $\frac{a_2}{-a_1}=\frac{\sin(\theta}{\cos(\theta)}$ giving $\frac{a_2}{-a_1}=\frac{a_1}{a_2}.$ Here you need to consider when $\cos(\theta)=0$ as a separate case. Thus, $a_2^2=-a_1^2.$ Why does this imply $a_1=a_2=0?$